# FACE API : Resource Not Found for end point url

Tags: python

I just tried to run MS's example face API python code. But my code cannot get response from HTTPs. I wrote my collect api key and end point.
This end point-`face_api_url` only response

```
{ "error": { "code": "ResourceNotFound", "message": "The requested
 resource was not found." } }
```

What should I do? Please help me!!

here is my source code:

```
subscription_key = 'I wrote my KEY'
assert subscription_key
face_api_url = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0'


image_url = 'https://how-old.net/Images/faces2/main007.jpg'


import requests
from IPython.display import HTML

headers = { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
faces = response.json()

print(faces)
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search and comparison leads me to believe that you're doing [this tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python). From the looks of it, you have the wrong url, which (per that tutorial) should be: `https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0`**/detect**

*(bold added to highlight the missing path)*

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the site administrator has decided that the site should act as if it does not exist to clients that do not show their User-Agent in their headers.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
           'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
           'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=image_data)
response.raise_for_status()
faces = response.json()
print(faces)
```

This solved it for me!